# Which OAuth2.0 grant should I choose

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0

Referring to this [decision template](http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/which-grant/) for choosing the right grant type for my application.
[image]
I am not quite sure, which grant type to use.

The scenario is as followed:

1. Resource Server, WebApi 2.0 (Domain A)
2. Authorization Server (Domain B)
3. ASP.NET MVC Application, makes jQuery based Ajax requests to Resource Server

Basically what I want is, that all loggedIn Users of my MVC application can make ajax requests from the Client Browser directly to the Resource Server instantly using Bearer Auth.

The Access Token owner will be the Browser User Agent, which will store the access token in local storage for example, right? Every loggedIn User will have it's own auth token. The clients (Browsers) of the MVC app are "First party" clients, right?

What grant type would it be at the end--> Password grant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grant_type for your password will be "password" it self. For instance take this example from my application:

**JAVASCRIPT** - Auth Service using angular with OAuth2.0 and c# WebAPI 2.0 (MVC) - Pattern used.

```
return $http({
                url: $rootScope.globals.apiPath + "/someController/token",
                method: 'POST',
                data: "userName=" + encodeURIComponent(username) +
                      "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password) +
                      "&Scope=" + "website" +
                     "&grant_type=password" + // here I pass the type as password to the web api
                     "&client_id=clientIdExample",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            });
```

This is then processed on the API using the grant resource owner credentials like so:

**C# - API**

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var source = LogUtility.InitializeContext(this.GetType());

            try
            {
                var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<String>("clientAllowedOrigin") ?? "*";

                context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

                var signOnContext = await new AccessControlBusinessLogicLayer().LoadUserSignOnContextOrDefaultByCredentials(context.Options.AuthenticationType, context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (signOnContext == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");

                    return;
                }

                context.OwinContext.Set<String>("userSecurityStamp", signOnContext.SecurityStamp);

                var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties(
                    new Dictionary<String, String>
                    {
                        { "client_id", context.ClientId }
                    });
                var authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(signOnContext.Identity, authenticationProperties);

                if (context.Scope[0].ToLower() == "website")
                {
                    using (var userContext = new AccessControlContext())
                    {
                        using (var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(
                            var user = AccessBL.LoadUserOrDefaultByUserName(context.UserName);

                            var userId = user.Id;
                        }
                    }
                }

                context.Validated(authenticationTicket);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }
```

This will check the grant and the current context for the current user. Hope this helps for the ambiguity. This means that the password grant will be the grant resources from the web client and not the implicit.

Comment: Hm, I would rather request a Bearer auth token during the mvc application login process (Username+Password) and then just send back the auth token (Bearer) to the Browser client. And the Bearer token is then sent via Authorization Header using jQuery Ajax to the Bearer secured WebApi on every request. This would be the process I would imagine it, when using password grant. Right? Because i don't want to pass user credentials to the browser and then forth to the Resource Server.

Comment: Spot on that is exactly what you need to do, you only send the bearer to the secure web api through the requested headers and yes you never want to pass user credentials back and forth to the browser, that would subject it to a security risk. So from what I can see in the process diagram if you use the 'password' as the grant type you should be heading in the right direction. And I also did a lot of research on this and I came up using this solution as they follow best practices: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: But in your example, you call the token service endpoint using credentials via angular.js, which is running in  a browser...?!

Comment: As per the previous exmple link I am not sending the user credentials, the only thing I send to identify the user is the access_token and some sort of refresh token used in an interceptor service. There is no physical credentials like passwords or usernames send to the client's browser. The access token is the only thing getting send back and forth to identify logged in clients, update sessions and handle requests. My API back-end has a handler to handle these requests and extract the "credentials" from the request headers.

Comment: And obviously the grant_type, which is set to string "password".

Comment: Thanks for your support!